# Sync new library with OneDrive for Business programmatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, onedrive-for-business

We're getting ready to start a SharePoint 2013 (on-premise) deployment, creating several team sites with document libraries.  Some of the team members are mobile (laptops), and I'd like to get them set up with a OneDrive For Business synced copy of their team library.

Is there a way I can script the creation of the sync relationship so I don't have to ask all the users to manually visit their team site library and click the Sync link?  Any method of automating this would be helpful, whether it be PowerShell, registry entries, .NET code, etc.

Comment: I've had the joy of troubleshooting ODfB, and found that a lot of the settings are in the registry. I wonder if values can be added there to automate it.